# Is there any graph for drawing a function in terms of another function?

Tags: plotting

My goal is to investigate chaos in a system. I need the following `Plot`:
[image: Chaos]

I have to draw a function in terms of another function.
My codes are:

```
x[t_] = 0.349 - 0.14018692623289142*t^0.99 - 
  0.1492985284406859*t^1.98 + 0.037669359022781464*t^2.9699999999999998

y[t_] = -0.35046731558222854*t^0.99 + 0.14218907470541514*t^1.98 + 
  0.018834679511390732*t^2.9699999999999998

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

But I do not know what `Plot` should I use. I need a plot that x-axis be x[t] and y-axis be y[t] (Phase diagram).  Any segestions?

Comment: You included the answer of your question in your example, so which additional suggestions you are expecting?

Comment: @ Ulrich Neumann I need a plot similar to the image is presented. I need a plot that x-axis be `x[t]` and y-axis be `y[t]`.

Comment: @ Bahram Agheli:  `ParametricPlot[{x[t],y[t]},{t,...}]] in 2D` or  `ParametricPlot3D[{x[t],y[t],z[t]},{t,...}]] in 3D` are the functions you're looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an example from [NDSolve >> Applications >> Ordinary Differential Equations >> Lorenz equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
   Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], 
   Derivative[1][z][t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, 
 {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; 

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#4] &), BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2., -2., 5}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t] , y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#4] &), 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

For the 2D slice `{y[t] , x[t] + z[t]}`, we get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possiblity is to use `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` along with the `Line` primitive. This will plot kglr's example much quicker, but it also provides a bit less user interface (e.g. coloring has to be done by hand)...

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
    Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], 
    Derivative[1][z][t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

f = t \[Function] Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[[1]]];

pts = Table[f[t], {t, 0., 200., 0.01}];

Graphics3D[Line[pts], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]

Table[Graphics[{Thin, Line[pts[[All, bla]]]}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}[[bla]]], {bla, 
  Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not gain plot for `x[t_] = 0.349 - 0.14018692623289142*t^0.99 - 
  0.1492985284406859*t^1.98 + 0.037669359022781464*t^2.9699999999999998`,`y[t_] = -0.35046731558222854*t^0.99 + 0.14218907470541514*t^1.98 + 
  0.018834679511390732*t^2.9699999999999998` and `z[t_] = -0.18 - 0.03163243679323839*t^0.99 - 0.002807368461008599*t^1.98 - 0.08347051618381417*t^2.9699999999999998`.

Comment: You merely have to erase `/. sol[[1]]` in the definition of `f`.